# hirzebruch spectral sequence for a cohomology theory on a subcategory of TOP

Tags: homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences, infinity-categories

The answer to my question is probably going to be 'yes, sometimes'.  So I'll give my motivation first.

I am trying to give a short argument that for a fibration $F \hookrightarrow E \to B$ and a $\pi_1(E)$ module $M$, there is a spectral sequence $H^*(B, \mathscr{H}^*(F,M)) \Rightarrow H^*(E,M)$, where $M$ is given the $\pi_*(F)$ module structure via $\pi_1(F) \to \pi_1(E) \to Aut(M)$.

I want to say that given a topological space $E$, and a $\pi_1(E)$ module $M$, cohomology with local coefficients in $M$ is a 'cohomology theory on the flow subcategory of objects in TOP that map into $E$'

(All of the Eilenberg steenrod axioms hold on objects from this category except the dimension axiom)

Putting aside the problem that I don't know exactly what 'cohomology theory on a (fancy word) subcategory of hTOP' is supposed to be,

> Suppose one has a generalized cohomology theory $E$ on a 2-subcategory of the 2-category hTOP.(In my case, I want to take this to be the category of objects in TOP equipped with a mapping to a space with a given fundamental group). For any fibration $F \hookrightarrow E \to B$ with $F \to E$ in my subcategory, is there a spectral sequence $H^*(B, E^*(F)) \Rightarrow E^*(E)$?

I know I have been sloppy on categorical details, but I hope it is clear what I am trying to do, even if I don't know the right language to express myself.

---

edit(8/15):  I don't think that there is - take the case when $F=pt$.  Then we get that twisted coefficients is the same as untwistied coefficients.  I would be grateful if someone could find the right question to ask here that has a better chance of having a positive answer.